# Windows Form Write to Console

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I am simply trying to open the console and write a single line and execute it with the console staying open once the line is written. Currently, the command line is opening blank and not writing anything. Any way to fix this?

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo hello");
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("pause");
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Type in the Windows Run dialog: `cmd /K "echo hello"` - it works like you need. Now do the same in the program, using Process command line parameters. No need in input/output redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You could most likely just issue a pause:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("pause");
```

Should solve it.

Remember to add:

```
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
```

If that does not work then most likely still an issue, as reported at Microsoft regarding CMD specifically and output.   See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/609801/unable-to-redirect-only-the-standard-input-of-process-cmd-exe-or-batch-file-from-windows-form-application

Comment: The command prompt is still blank. It is not the issue of not exiting. It is the issue that the text is not showing (or executing) in the prompt.

Comment: Surely RedirectStandardOutput should be false then?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

This works perfect for me:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("pause");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" ");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir /p");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        cmd.WaitForExit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes the command prompt to not open at all. It seems it may just flash open and quickly close.

Comment: I edited my original. Can you confirm yours is the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K \"echo hello\"";
        cmd.Start();
```